# How to get the original IDocHostUIHandler provided by Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, bho, mshtml

In [the documentation of the IDocHostUIHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), there is a paragraph about the default UI handler provided by IE when talking about a memory leak caused by using ICustomDoc from a BHO:

```
To avoid a memory leak: 

 1. Always forward the IDocHostUIHandler::ShowUI and
IDocHostUIHandler::HideUI methods to the original handler. 
 2. Release the pointer to the original UI handler when your object is called
with IObjectWithSite::SetSite(NULL).
```

How to get the host interface in order to release it?

Comment: how you have solved 2nd issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not officially supported, you can still get a reference to the original `IDocHostUIHandler` in order to pass calls through on all of the methods you don't plan on overriding in your BHO.

First you cast the document as an `IOleObject` and then call `GetClientSite` in order to obtain the original `IOleClientSite` object. This can then be cast to either `IDocHostUIHandler` or `IOleCommandTarget` in order to call the methods from those interfaces on the original handler/target.

Here is an example code snippet from the DocumentComplete event of a C# BHO (`Explorer` is an instance of `ShDocVw.WebBrowserClass`, `UIHandler` is my own `IDocHostUIHandler` class which passes calls through to the object passed in the initializer, and all of the interfaces were taken directly from http://pinvoke.net):

```
IOleObject obj = Explorer.Document as IOleObject;
if (obj != null)
{
    IOleClientSite cs = null;
    obj.GetClientSite(ref cs);

    if (cs != null)
    {
        ICustomDoc cDoc = Explorer.Document as ICustomDoc;
        if (cDoc != null)
        {
            cDoc.SetUIHandler(new UIHandler(cs));
        }
    }
}
```

This was adapted from C++ code available in the PopupBlocker project available here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4003/Popup-Window-Blocker

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me to solve the problem of dropping files. Without this, dropping a file would only open it as a URL but not fire "drop" events on the DOM. Just have to use the IOleClientSite from the GetDropTarget implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The whole passage nowadays reads

> **It is not intended to replace an existing IDocHostUIHandler that is
>   provided by Internet Explorer** or the WebBrowser control. If you try to
>   replace that interface from a Browser Helper Object (BHO) using
>   ICustomDoc, you may experience unexpected behavior such as memory
>   leaks.

So it is simply not supported what you are trying to do (at least officially).